in JavaScript navigator.clipboard.readText() is returning [object Promise] even though it is awaited
In the following example, highlight and copy "this is text". That is what should be added to the clipboard. However [object Promise] is added instead. readText() is awaited so this is the incorrect result. How do I make this work?
<html>
This is text

<script>
document.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    var result = textCopied();
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', result);
    e.preventDefault();
});

async function textCopied() {
var clipboardContents = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
return clipboardContents 
}
</script>
</html>


clipboardContents is an awaited value. result is not.

You have to make the listener callback function async and await the call.


document.addEventListener('copy', async function(e) { // here
  var result = await textCopied(); // and here
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', result);
  e.preventDefault();
});

async function textCopied() {
  var clipboardContents = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  return clipboardContents
}
This is text



Also, since the function is async, just return the inner call:
async function textCopied() {
  return navigator.clipboard.readText();
}

